# Need to loop till the array inside the array has value

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, typescript

I need to loop(map) the array till inside array have value. If inside array is empty need to stop the loop

```js
var parent = {
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'test1',
      children: [
        {
          id: '2',
          title: 'test 21',
          children: [
            {
              id: '3',
              title: 'test3',
              children: [
                {
                  id: '4',
                  title: 'test5',
                  children: []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Loop the array till inside the children array has value.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have to display the title name from all children array..by checking if children has array.

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish? Is there an expected result?

Comment: Just i need to loop  array to display all  children's title.

Comment: But your structure is quite different, is at an object which has a property as children where its an array of objects, because as per your question the value of the children will be empty array since same property will be overwritten

Comment: You can use array.map which will return a new array and can be used in jsx, kindly check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can recursively loop through the children array and push the title to another array.
Then can loop through this new array to render titles.

```
export default function App() {
  const titleArray = []

  const recursive = (children) => {
    children.map((newChild) => {
      newChild.title && titleArray.push(newChild.title)
      if(newChild.children) {
        recursive(newChild.children)
      }
    })
  }
  recursive(parent.children)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {titleArray.map((title, index) => (
         <div key={index}>{title}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox URL: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-archimedes-0hzy2?file=/src/App.js:668-1111

Answer (score 0):

Check this one.

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const App = () => {
  let parent = {
    children: [
      {
        id: "49",
        title: "test1",
        type: "domain_content_root",
        children: [
          {
            id: "71",
            title: "test 21",
            type: "content_folder",
            children: [
              {
                id: "71",
                title: "test3",
                type: "content_folder",
                children: [
                  {
                    id: "71",
                    title: "test5",
                    type: "content_folder",
                    children: []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };

  let getValues = (object) => {
    return object && typeof object === "object"
      ? [
          ...("title" in object ? [object.title] : []),
          ...Object.values(object).flatMap(getValues)
        ]
      : [];
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {getValues(parent.children).map((title) => (
        <div>{title}</div>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/looping-an-array-of-data-grk7v)

Comment: Can you please now see the edited array. My array format is like that.

Comment: @Kavitha I have updated kindly check, got some busy with other stuff, let me know if it helped you or not